# Symfony2 formbuilder field with subtype -> Internal Server Error (InvalidArgumentException)

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony2 form that's called "item". It is defined in ItemType and looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('name', TextType::class,
            array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank()
                )
            )
        ), 
        ->add('item_entry', ItemEntryType::class, array(
            'required' => true
        ))          
}
```

now when I try to send a post request with item_entry missing entirely, it throws an internal server error and the log tells me it was an InvalidArgumentException, "Expected argument of type 'Bundle\Entity\Something', NULL given".

ItemEntry has a field with the something entity. But my problem is, shouldn't Symfony2 realize that itemEntry wasn't submitted at all and not try to validate specific fields? What I would expect is an error that item_entry was not submitted instead of this.

Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'required' => false on your item_entry form field.
Also you are missing ';' after the last ->add method

Edit:
If it must be 'required' => true, you can handle this case by removing it from the form dynamically in a PRE_SUBMIT event:

```
$formData = $event->getData();
if(!isset($formData["item_entry"])) {
   $form = $event->getForm();
   $form->remove("item_entry");
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: item_entry should be required though